# Как правильно ввести название столбца бд для запроса

Tags: c#

Допусти, у меня в phpmyadmin есть таблица квадратов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я в phpmyadmin ввожу команду SELECT '3' FROM 'kv' WHERE desatki=1 и получаю значение 169.
И теперь я этот же запрос хочу реализовать в C#, но только чтобы значения вводил пользователь.

```
float desatki = Convert.ToInt32(desatki.Text);
float ed = Convert.ToInt32(ed.Text);
desatki.ToString();
ed.ToString();
```

Опустим код обеспечивающий подключение к бд.

```
SELECT `@ed` FROM `kv` WHERE desatki=@desatki
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desatki", desatki);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ed", ed);
string kv1 = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

По итогу код выдает ошибку в строке string kv1 = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());, о том что не понимает, что такое @ed. Как это исправить?

Comment: Насколько я помню, названия таблиц и столбцов не могут быть параметрами запроса. Это не только для `C#` верно, у питоновских библиотек так же. Это общая практика. Вам придётся интерполяцией строк или ещё каким-то форматированием строк подставлять название столбца. Что не хорошо, и лучше вы как-то по-другому спроектируйте БД и программу.

Comment: А как я это могу сделать?  Как мне поменять БД? Что делать если я БД не могу изменить?

Comment: Ну по-нормальному вам нужно нормализовать таблицу, т.е. единицы и десятки должны стать колонками, по которыми вы выбираете результат из таблицы, а сам результат должен быть в отдельной колонке с названием, например, `result`.

Comment: А как сейчас, вам проще выбирать из таблицы всю строку, а потом брать из неё нужную колонку уже не в запросе, а в коде программы.

Comment: Напишите, какую именно СУБД используете. В некоторых есть возможность указать имя столбца параметром. Например, в Sql Server его нужно обернуть в функцию `quotename`.

Comment: Зачем константы хранить в БД? Почему квадрат не посчитать умножением? В чём смысл задачи?

Comment: Кстати, `desatki.ToString()` - это что? Как вы думаете, что делает эта строка? (ничего) Если нужно преобразование в строку (зачем?), то это делается так `string desatkiText = desatki.ToString();`.